# Convert String to Float/Integer/Double (numeric value) in EL

Tags: jsf, integer, double, el, string-conversion

following problem:
I got a string from a backing bean. This string contains numeric values. I pick the first numeric value with the JSTL functions split and replace.
Now I have the right value. Problem - as string :(

I need this numeric String as numeric float, double or integer in a EL expression to compare to values.

Now to the main problem: I cannot access to the backing bean, or adding a new libary to the server. I can only edit the template files.

This are the available libaries/namespaces:

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pass="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: "*I cannot access to the backing bean, or adding a new library to the server. I can only edit the template files.*" Why? Is there bureaucracy at your workplace? It would have been easier, if the value had been passed through a JSF converter, perhaps, a custom converter depending upon the need.

Comment: Then wrap the bean, extend it and add an additional method in there. Way easier... or is this the same as 'adding a new library'? Then I suggest to find a new customer!

Comment: i only can access and edit the template on my self.

Comment: Weird situation... https://www.google.nl/search?q=convert+string+to+integer+in+EL